# spring authenticationManager.authenticate(token) stop and not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, authentication

```
System.out.println("=======");
UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken token = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                user.getEmail(), user.getPassword());

try {
    // 로그인
    System.out.println( authenticationManager.toString() );
    System.out.println(123123);
    Authentication auth = authenticationManager.authenticate(token);
    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(auth);
    repository.saveContext(SecurityContextHolder.getContext(), request, response);

    response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK); 
    System.out.println("=======ok");
    //map.put("success", true);
    //map.put("returnUrl", getReturnUrl(request, response));
} catch (BadCredentialsException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_NOT_FOUND);
}
```

This code is running successfully on my local server, but on OS server it stops.

> org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager@59f2fb2b
>   123123 org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@8cba1f58: Principal: id@gmail.com; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: false; Details: null; Not granted any authorities

OS server is win R2 2008
localserver win 2010

What's wrong?

Comment: What do you mean 'stop' ? Any error message.